# SQLite query with byte[] WHERE clause

Tags: java, android, sql, blob

From an Android SQLite database point of view -  I have a table which has a field with BLOB type and then I want to query this table contents based on this BLOB field.

I can insert my BLOB field using `ContentValues` and retrieve it using:

```
cursor.getBlob(0)// index
```

I just can't figure out how to query this table contents based on this BLOB field and have found nothing about this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't query the (textual?  binary?  other?) contents of a blob.

If you look, you'll see the contents is in hex:

EXAMPLE:  X'53514C697465'.

Suggestions:

Create a new text column, e.g. "blob_index".  You can search on the "index" column, then fetch the blob.

Alternatively, just store the data as "text".

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can query on a blob.  One needs to use the hex() function on the query.

For example I'm using UUIDs in my database rows as a unique key that I can generate locally and still be sure of uniqueness on the server.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE example (_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
>                       uuid BLOB NON NULL UNIQUE,
>                       ...)
> ```

When inserting data the following works:

> ```
> final ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
> values.put(Contract.Line.COL_UUID,
>            UuidFactory.toBlob(uuid));
> ```

Given a query URI in the form:

> ```
> content://package.example.com/example/uuid/11112222-3333-0444-0555-666677778888
> ```

the query becomes:

> ```
> final SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
> return db.query(table, projection,
>                 "hex(uuid) = ?",
>                 new String[] { UuidFactory.toHex(uri.getLastPathSegment()) },
>                 null, null, null, null);
> ```

In `UuidFactory` (which also contains the code to generate new UUIDs) the follow static functions are defined thus:

> ```
> @NonNull
> public static String toHex(@NonNull final UUID uuid) {
>     return String.format("%016X%016X",
>                         uuid.getMostSignificantBits(),
>                         uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
> }
>
> @NonNull
> public static String toHex(@NonNull final String uuid) {
>     return toHex(UUID.fromString(uuid));
> }
>
> @NonNull
> public static byte[] toBlob(@NonNull final UUID uuid) {
>     final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
>     buf.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
>     buf.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
>     return buf.array();
> }
> ```

And for completeness:

> ```
> @NonNull
> public static UUID fromBlob(@NonNull final byte[] array) {
>     final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
>     buf.mark();
>     buf.put(array);
>     buf.reset();
>     final long msb = buf.getLong();
>     final long lsb = buf.getLong();
>     return new UUID(msb, lsb);
> }
> ```